# Audio reactive animation

Tags: animation, audio

I know is possible to make things react to an audio intensity, but is there any way I can make it react to the different frequencies?

Comment: Yes. The common way in blender to  "_make things react to audio intensity_"  is bake sound to f-curve.  The default settings cover a wide frequency band.  The frequency range can be set using the `low` and 'high` properties.  Script version here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30786/15543 (for 2.7x)  For example to bake A4 note set high and low to 440(Hz). I wrote an addon for this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39241/15543 but lost interest (while 2.8 came around and had to wait for new `bgl` module)   It is also possible via animation nodes addon.

Comment: Thank you very much.